# Unity 2018.3 HDRP - Change material color programatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the new HDRP/LitTesselation shader.

I would like to change the `Base Color + Opacity` at runtime:

[image: img]

I added this code to the game object's script:

```
void start()
{
        Color color = new Color(100, 50, 100, 150);

        //Fetch the Renderer from the GameObject
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        //Set the main Color of the Material to green
        rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
}
```

But it generates an `Hidden/InternalShaderError` error in the shader.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by modifying these lines as follows:

```
rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("HDRenderPipeline/LitTessellation"); 
rend.material.SetColor("_BaseColor", color);
```

Comment: Do mark the this answer accepted and close this question if you think this is the correct solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is for HDRP/Lit:

```
private Material _mat;

void Start()
{
    Renderer nRend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    _mat = nRend.material;
}

void Update()
{
    Color nNew = //do whatever you want here
    _mat.SetColor("_BaseColor", nNew);
}
```

I once read that "sharedMaterial" should be used instead of "material".
However, I think that was just a typo. "sharedMaterial" would affect ALL HDRP/Lit materials, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with this line:

```
Color color = new Color(100, 50, 100, 150);
```

According to the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html), colors should be initialized with values from 0 to 1 instead of with larger numbers. My guess is that if you change the value of your `color` variable accordingly that will solve the issue. The rest of your code seems to follow the form found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html).

Try out the following:

```
Color color = new Color(0.39f, 0.196f, 0.39f, 0.588f);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it, but still getting same error on shader: "Hidden/InternalShaderError".